# Tornar json remoto em string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Como é possível retornar o valor de um json remoto e ler como string, exemplo quando eu recebo o json ele imprime todo o resultado como na imagem abaixo.
[image: Todo Resultado do json]
codigo abaixo:

```
var https = require('https');
    var optionsget = {
        host : 'the-evie.com',
        port : 443,
        path : '/playerscript/pc/Droust', 
        method : 'GET'
    };
    console.info('Options prepared:');
    console.info(optionsget);
    console.info('Do the GET call');

var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });
});
reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

o que eu queria era tornar isso filtrado como por exemplo o username, fosse capaz de receber o valor pela key, ou seja key username valor Droust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converta o Json em um objeto.

`var obj = JSON.parse(text);`

Depois é só pegar o valor que você deseja desse objeto.

`var user = obj.username;`

Dessa forma sua variável user vai receber o valor Droust.

Da uma lida aqui também, pode te ajudar: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: como é possivel usar ele fora da função, em uma outra função?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Usar o que fora da função?

Comment: a variavel ela existe dentro do         var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {

        }); porem não consigo usar ela fora

Comment: Acho que agora entendi. Você pode declarar o var obj fora do contexto das suas funções. E dentro da sua função você faz a variável obj receber seu texto e ser convertida em objeto. E aí você poderá usar ela onde você quiser no seu código.

Comment: `@`SamuelHenriqueRizzon (cc @CarlosEduardo) se `https.request` for assíncrono isso não é verdade!